# How should I proceed with this type of dataset and requirement?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

Suppose I have a dataset where I want to give input of up-to 30 lines (can be variable with min 5 available) these lines are timestamps of every minute and want my model to predict output of next 5 lines(the output for training is also available) which model should be used or possible and how should I fit my data for the model?

Basically if you still don't get it I want to get my model to predict the value for a column for the next 5 mins from the input:

Example Input:

```
             Datetime       SCP      CPS%   ExtP1   ExtP2    ComFut
  2022-01-07 11:16:00  37890.75      3.55  439.05  414.75    104.30
  2022-01-07 11:17:00  37892.50      5.53  441.75  411.10    109.30
  2022-01-07 11:18:00  37919.95      5.37  426.80  425.00    112.75
  2022-01-07 11:19:00  37948.50      5.82  411.50  437.35    114.45
  2022-01-07 11:20:00  37928.40      5.48  421.90  428.40    108.90
  2022-01-07 11:21:00  37908.15      6.14  434.05  417.10    108.30
  2022-01-07 11:22:00  37916.25      5.49  428.80  422.75    113.80
  2022-01-07 11:23:00  37909.85      6.19  433.85  418.40    114.85
  2022-01-07 11:24:00  37893.55      4.50  439.35  414.00    104.50
  2022-01-07 11:25:00  37891.10      5.14  440.95  410.50    108.40
  2022-01-07 11:26:00  37899.80      7.81  441.80  409.60    117.00
  2022-01-07 11:27:00  37915.85      7.85  432.80  417.15    124.10
  2022-01-07 11:28:00  37934.45      7.58  420.35  425.20    120.55
  2022-01-07 11:29:00  37919.75      4.76  424.95  425.40    111.60
  2022-01-07 11:30:00  37920.05      5.95  426.45  422.55    112.50
  2022-01-07 11:31:00  37924.50      8.46  427.35  418.50    121.50
  2022-01-07 11:32:00  37937.50      9.03  422.60  425.10    122.85
  2022-01-07 11:33:00  37946.80      5.50  410.35  435.75    120.75
  .
  .
  .
  2022-01-07 11:42:00  37886.25      4.35  440.00  407.90    103.85
  2022-01-07 11:43:00  37887.15      5.18  441.75  407.15    108.85
  2022-01-07 11:44:00  37890.80      6.70  442.75  405.75    115.45
  2022-01-07 11:45:00  37895.75      5.17  437.15  411.40    106.25
```

Example Output:

```
             Datetime       SCP
  2022-01-07 11:46:00  37793.10
  2022-01-07 11:47:00  37787.45
  2022-01-07 11:48:00  37799.25
  2022-01-07 11:49:00  37765.70
  2022-01-07 11:50:00  37718.10
```

I have problem with using the variable number of inputs fitting to the models I've tried using many ML models but its to no avail I get the error saying the shape don't match for the Input and output. What should I do and use in this case and what models are better for my case?

Comment: Welcome, Stack Exchange has specific sites about data science, machine learning and related topics. See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help